# Herencia en spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo que crear libros mediante una fabrica, un book es una clase especifica de Writte en un futuro puede existir otros tipos como revista, papers, ensayos etc.

La clase especifica es Book que hereda de Writte

```
public class Book extends Writte{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String title;

    @Column(name = "date")
    Date date;
}
```

tengo la clase general el cual tiene el author

```
public abstract class Writte {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="author_id")
    Author author;

    public  void setAuthor(Author author){
        this.author=author;
    }

    public  Author getAuthor(){
        return this.author;
    }

}
```

Ahora quiero crear books mediante una fabrica, aqui esta mi fabrica:

```
public class Factory {
    @Autowired
    BookRepository bookRepository;

    public Book createBook(Book book) {
        Book bookRecovery = bookRepository.findOne(book.getId());
        Book bookCreate;
        if (bookRecovery == null) {
            bookCreate = bookRepository.save(book);
        } else {
            bookRecovery.setTitle(book.getTitle());
            bookRecovery.setDate(book.getDate());
            bookCreate = bookRepository.save(bookRecovery);
        }
        return bookCreate;
    }
}
```

esta bien la organizacion? factory debe ser un servicio?

Comment: Las clases que implementan métodos de acceso a base de datos deben ser @Repository

Comment: Si deseas que tu factory haga el autowire del repositorio, esta debe ser un `@Bean`, `@Service` o `@Component`.